# How to get the currently logged in user's role in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to get the currently logged in user's role in wordpress?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you have the user id ($user_id) something like this should work:

```
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );

if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
        echo $role;
}
```

Get the user id from your session.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't know the user id, this function will help you (put it in your theme functions.php file)

```
function get_user_role() {
    global $current_user;

    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    return $user_role;
}
```

And then, in your template you can get user role by calling get_user_role().

Found it [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-users-role#post-1600295).

Comment: This method is not applicable if I have two or more roles added in a user, the reason is it only return single or first role that is being added to the user, shifted using array_shift PHP function.

Comment: Note that `$current_user` always exist and by default is filled with empty attributes, so although this code looks like you'll get object access and index problems, it actually works. The returned role for a new visitor will be `NULL`.

Comment: For future readers: Using global should be avoided as much as possible. Keep your code predictable

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I thought I'd add this 2023 option for getting the currently logged in user's role in WordPress. By default, WordPress users only have one role, but there are plugins and themes that can extend that feature giving users multiple roles, so I wanted to provide options for that too.

First, add this function somewhere to your website, probably at the bottom of your active theme's **functions.php** file.

```
/**
 * Get Current User Roles
 *
 * @param bool $return_array Optional. If true, will return an array of all roles. Otherwise, will return just the first role. Default is false.
 *
 * @return string|array Returns the current user's role(s) based on parameters. Empty string or array if user is not logged in or has no roles.
 */
function au_get_current_user_roles($return_array = false) {

    // Retrieves the current user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 

    // Checks if user is logged in and has roles
    if($current_user->exists() && count($current_user->roles)) {
        if($return_array) { return $current_user->roles; } // Return all roles as array
        return $current_user->roles[0]; // Return just the first role as a string
    }
    if($return_array) { return array(); } // Return empty array
    return ''; // Return empty string
}
```

To use the function to check if a user has a specific role (e.g. `administrator`) where users can only have one role, you'd use the function like this:

```
if('administrator' == au_get_current_user_roles()) {
    // Do something for admins only
}
```

Now if your users can have multiple roles and you want to check if they have a specific one (e.g. `administrator`), you can do it like this:

```
if(in_array('administrator', au_get_current_user_roles(true))) {
    // Do something for admins only
}
```

Now those examples above just checked if a user is a specific role (`administrator`), but what if you want to do something for users that are either an admin or an editor? Or both? You can do something like this:

```
$allowed_roles = array('administrator', 'editor');
if(count(array_intersect($allowed_roles, au_get_current_user_roles(true)))) {
    /* Do something for users who are admins, users who 
       are editors, and users who are both admin and users */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_role_by_id( $id ) {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { return false; }

    $oUser = get_user_by( 'id', $id );
    $aUser = get_object_vars( $oUser );
    $sRole = $aUser['roles'][0];
    return $sRole;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php global $current_user; //get the current user
echo $current_user->roles[0]); //display the current user's role
?>
```